# Functions of Random Variables - I am not sure if I am understanding this problem correctly.

Tags: probability

Let T be an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda$. Let X be a discrete random variable defined as X = k if $k \leq T < k+1$ and k = 0, 1, 2, ...

Find the PMF of X.

I am not sure if I am doing this problem correctly. Here is my approach.

$F_x(k \leq T < k+1) = F_t(k+1) - F_t(k)$

= $(1 - e^{-\lambda (k+1)} - (1 - e^{-\lambda k})$

= $-e^{-\lambda(k+1)} + e^{-\lambda k}$

From there, I differentiate:

$f_x(k) = \lambda e^{-\lambda(k+1)} - \lambda e^{-\lambda k}$

I am unsure if I did this correctly - perhaps because I am misunderstanding something. Perhaps, what is the purpose of defining X = k in the given question?

Comment: you meant $F(k+1) - F(k)$

Comment: Yeah it is too early... Fixed.

Comment: Apart from that, what is the point of defining X = k? Is my overall "strategy" correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $X$ is discrete, so differentiating doesn't really make sense.

You need to compute $p[X=k]$ .

You have $p[X=k] = p[T < k+1] - p[T \le k]  = (1-e^{-\lambda (k+1)}) - (1-e^{-\lambda k}) = e^{-\lambda k} (1-e^{-\lambda})$.

As a quick check, note that $\sum_{k \ge 0} p[X=k] = 1$.

Comment: Jesus. It is time for coffee. I was wondering why something felt really wrong. That was it. Thank you.

Comment: I understand entirely! (Lack of caffeine, that is :-), not much else that I understand.)

Comment: BTW. I think the very last term should be $1 + e^{-\lambda}$?

EDIT: Nevermind. Time for coffee. :-)

Comment: I have many errors, will fix shortly after another caffeine treatment.

Comment: Haha yeah. I redact my nevermind! Fun with exponents commences.

Comment: I think it is mostly correct now :-).

Comment: Huh. Strange. I am getting $e^{-\lambda k} (\frac{-1}{e^{\lambda}} + 1)$.

It was because I got $e^{-\lambda (k+1)}$ expanded out to $e^{-\lambda k -\lambda}$

Comment: There must be a $k$ in there somewhere...